# how to convert a data frame structure and expand it

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(Hour = c("1hr", "2hr", "3hr", "4hr"), Country1 = c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 2L), Country2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Include = c(4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

to be exact the data looks like this

```
Hour Country1 Country2 Include
 1hr        5        3       4
 2hr        4        3       3
 3hr        4        2       2
 4hr        2        1       2
```

I am trying to expand the data and make it look like this . for example Country1 at 1hr is 5. I put 5 zeros but when it goes to 2hr then it loses 1, so I put 4 zeros and one 1. in 3 hours it is 4 so it is the same as 2 hours and I put 4 zeros. in 4 hour, it is 2 and when it is compares to 3 hours, it is 2 number lower so I put 2 zeros and two 1. something like the following

```
data    status  Hour
Country1    0   1
Country1    0   1
Country1    0   1
Country1    0   1
Country1    0   1
Country2    0   1
Country2    0   1
Country2    0   1
include     0   1
include     0   1
include     0   1
include     0   1
Country1    0   2
Country1    0   2
Country1    0   2
Country1    0   2
Country1    1   2
Country2    0   2
Country2    0   2
Country2    0   2
include     0   2
include     0   2
include     0   2
include     1   2
```

The main output will look like this

```
output<- structure(list(data = c("Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", 
"Country1", "Country2", "Country2", "Country2", "include ", "include ", 
"include ", "include ", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", 
"Country1", "Country2", "Country2", "Country2", "include ", "include ", 
"include ", "include ", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", 
"Country2", "Country2", "Country2", "include ", "include ", "include ", 
"Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country1", "Country2", "Country2", 
"include ", "include "), status = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), Hour = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -42L))
```

After @arkun made a great code, I tested it with a larger data and it is not giving the answer when the hour is not sequential . so the output of df and df2 should be similar

```
df2 <- structure(list(Hour = c("5hr", "20hr", "30hr", "35hr"), Country1 = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 2L), Country2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Include = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Is the 'output' correct?

Comment: @akrun Yes the output is correct. each value is compared to the above value not to the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pivot to 'long' format, then `unnest` after creating a 'status' column by `rep`licating the 0, 1s based on the `lag` value by 'data'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
out <- df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Hour, names_to = 'data') %>%
    mutate(Hour = readr::parse_number(Hour)) %>%
   arrange(Hour, data) %>%
   group_by(data) %>% 
   mutate(value2 = lag(value, default = first(value))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(status = map2(value, value2, ~  {
      zeros <- numeric(.y)
      replace(zeros, tail(seq_along(zeros), .y - .x), 1)})) %>%
   select(-value, -value2) %>%
   unnest(c(status))%>%        
   select(data, status, Hour) 

dim(out)
#[1] 42  3
```

-checking with OP's 'output'

```
out %>%
    mutate(data = toupper(data)) %>%
    all.equal(output %>%
      mutate(data = trimws(toupper(data))), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: it is not giving the same output as I mentioned. please check, it adds extra data

Comment: @Learner thanks, I was checking it.  Here, I used `max(value)`.  Just wonder whether you need `lag` il.e. `df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Hour, names_to = 'data') %>%
   arrange(Hour, data) %>%
   group_by(data) %>% mutate(value2 = lag(value, default = first(value))) %>% ungroup %>%  mutate(status = map2(value, value2,
      ~ rep(c(0, 1), c(.y, .y - .x)))) %>% select(-value, -value2) %>% unnest(c(status)) %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: @Learner From what I understand it is checking the previous hour and make corrections or am I wrong?

Comment: You are absolutely right. however, above solution is much much closer but one mistake at the very end . look at 3hr and 4hr of country1. it should be 2 times 1 and two times 00. in your solution it is 3 times 0 and two times 1 , why?

Comment: @Learner now, it is 42

Comment: when the hour changes, it does not give the correct answer, can you please check on this example `structure(list(Hour = c("5hr", "20hr", "30hr", "35hr"), Country1 = c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 2L), Country2 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Include = c(4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))`

Comment: with the new df, it gives me 33 and not 42. both these df (the one in my question must give similar dimension and output

Comment: @Learner sure, will check on it.  It must be related to the replication

Comment: @Learner it is the `arrange` on the 'Hour' that creates the issue because it is not numeric, the first one was now '20hr'.  I changed the `parse_number` before the `arrange`, now it is giving 42 rows

Comment: the order changed which value to pick up